# Why is it unable to match?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why its unable to match?

```
  var d = $('#bstudylevel').val();  // Bachelor
  var g = $('#bfrench').val(); // Moedertaal
  var h = $('#bnederlands').val(); // Moedertaal

  switch(selected_language) { //NL
    case 'NL':
      if( ((d!=='Bachelor') || (d!=='Master') || (d!=='Doctoraat') ) && 
          ((g!=='Moedertaal') || (g!=='Zeer Goed') ) && 
          ((h!=='Moedertaal') || (h!=='Zeer Goed') )
      ) {
          console.log("You do not match the requirement: ", d, g, h);
          return false;
      }
      break;
    case 'FR':
      if( ((d!=='Bachelier') || (d!=='Master') || (d!=='Doctorat') ) && 
          ((g!=='Très bon')  || (g!=='Bon') ) && 
          ((h!=='Très bon')  || (h!=='Zeer Goed') )
      ) {
        console.log("You do not match the requirement: ", d, g, h);
        return false;
      }      
      break;
  }

  console.log('Expected output is this..., not above');
```

Output:

You do not match the requirement:  Bachelor Moedertaal Moedertaal

Comment: `(d!=='Master')` is `true`; `(g!=='Zeer Goed')` is `true`, I guess you can understand why now?

Comment: The actual question is, Why this question is unable to understand?

Comment: (d!=='Bachelor') || (d!=='Master') will always be true for whatever value of d

Comment: How does `selected_language` look like?

Comment: A little bit of common courtesy from the OP would of been nice... perhaps a description of the problem rather than a very terse statement.

Comment: Your `if` returns `true`, hence the output.

Comment: Maybe it would be easier and more readable to look for the value in an array of acceptable values.  For example, jQuery's `inArray()` method.  https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because in your code `d` has always a value that is true:

```
if (((d !== 'Bachelor') || (d !== 'Master') || (d !== 'Doctoraat')) && ((g !== 'Moedertaal') || (g !== 'Zeer Goed')) && ((h !== 'Moedertaal') || (h !== 'Zeer Goed')))
```

**e.g.**

```
d !== 'Master' //true,
d !== 'Doctoraat' //true
```

One solution could be to use an array with all degrees and use [Array.prototype.indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) as follow:

```
var d = 'Bachelor';
var g = 'Moedertaal';
var h = 'Moedertaal';
var degrees = ['Bachelor', 'Master', 'Doctoraat', 'Moedertaal', 'Zeer Goed', 'Moedertaal', 'Zeer Goed'];

case 'NL':
    //check if d meet the degrees requirements
    if (degrees.indexOf(d) !== -1) {
        console.log("You do not match the requirement: ", d, g, h);
        return false;
    }
break;
```

Answer (score 3):

In any expression like

```
((d!=='Bachelier') || (d!=='Master') || (d!=='Doctorat') )
```

consider that `d` can have only one value. Therefore, whatever `d` is, it will be not equal to one of those strings. It might be none of them, or it might be one of them, but it won't be all three.

Therefore the value of that will *always* be `true`.

Answer (score 1):

No worries, we'll help you. I made a fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/j9z8xyys/

```
var d = 'Bachelor';
var g = 'Moedertaal';
var h = 'Moedertaal';
selected_language = 'NL';
switch(selected_language) { //NL
    case 'NL':
        if( ((d!=='Bachelor') || (d!=='Master') || (d!=='Doctoraat') ) && 
        ((g!=='Moedertaal') || (g!=='Zeer Goed') ) && 
        ((h!=='Moedertaal') || (h!=='Zeer Goed') )) {
            console.log("A");
            return false;
        }
        break;
    case 'FR':
        if( ((d!=='Bachelier') || (d!=='Master') || (d!=='Doctorat') ) && 
        ((g!=='Très bon')  || (g!=='Bon') ) && 
        ((h!=='Très bon')  || (h!=='Zeer Goed'))) {
            console.log("B");
            return false;
        }      
        break;
    }
console.log("C");
```

It ends up going into the first console out just because the condition is met. What should the thing do, maybe its a good idea to rewrite it.